# How to get value out of .getProperty('style")

Tags: java, rft

`.getProperty("style")` outputs `TestObject(Ref:RemoteProxyReference{testContext:af4e390002a336, objectId:3171, testObjectClass:TestObject})`

while `to[0].getProperties()` outputs text hash where key "style" is presented `{... , style=DISPLAY: none, oncontrolselect=null Object, rowSpan=1, .....}`

**How can I get the value of the property with key style?**

here's sample of my code ...

```
TestObject[] to=null;
RegularExpression findRegExp1 = new RegularExpression(find_arguments[1], false) ;
RootTestObject root = getRootTestObject();
to = root.find(atDescendant(find_arguments[0],findRegExp1),false);

System.out.println(to[0].getProperty("style"));
System.out.println( to[0].getProperties());
```

Both methods are standard RFT methods. More info at [IBM Rational Functional Tester API Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.rational.test.ft.api.help/ApiReference/com/rational/test/ft/object/interfaces/RootTestObject.html)

Comment: It appears from your code sample that `getProperty()` is a custom method of whatever type is returned by `root.find(...)`.  Without the code for _at least_ `getProperty()`, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: @Jim: updated my question. Both methods are standard RFT methods. I cannot event see values of getProperty("style") when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket with IBM support and this is the final answer:

"*I have done the test in your website and confirmed the getProperty("style") output. It was a bug and has been fixed in RFT8.2.1.1. I confirmed that the getProperty method in RFT 8.2.1.1 works well.*"

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(to[0].getProperty("style"));
```

This invokes `toString()` on the value of `to[0].getProperty()`.  The object being returned by `getProperty()` likely has methods to retrieve various attributes, such as the text value, but produces the output you see for a simple `toString()`.

You are going to have to research this in the RFT documentation to determine which method provides the data you want.

Comment: `Returns the value of the specified property. If the property type is not a value class, getProperty registers the object in the software under test and returns a reference to the object. Registered object references are released by calling one of the unregister methods. ` hmm. How can I access the object getProperty("style") created?

Comment: You will have to figure out the type of the object. You haven't shown the declaration of `to` in your code.

Comment: The declaration is `TestObject[] to=null;` . How can I figure out?

Comment: What are the methods on `TestObject`?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.rational.test.ft.api.help/ApiReference/com/rational/test/ft/object/interfaces/TestObject.html

Answer (score 1):

I think "stlye" is a Non-Value property.
As the documentation states: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.rational.test.ft.api.help/ApiReference/com/rational/test/ft/object/interfaces/TestObject.html

> You can find the non-value properties by calling getNonValueProperties(). You can use the getProperty method to access both value and non-value properties. *If you access a non-value property, the property returns a TestObject that contains a reference to the (non-value) object in the software under test*.

you **cannot** access the content of that property.

Open up the Test Object Inspector and look if "style" is in the Non-Value Properties panel[image: Non Value properties in the Test Object Inspector]

I just tried with IE6 on a page and cannot read the "style" property.